# A rather special parsing of a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

Alright good people of stackOverflow, my question is on the broad subject of parsing. The information i want to obtain is on multiple positions on a text file marked by begin and end headers (special strings) on each appearance. I want to get everything that's between these headers. The code i have implemented so far seems somehow terribly inefficient (although not slow) and as you can see below makes use of two while statements.

```
with open(sessionFile, 'r') as inp_ses:
    curr_line = inp_ses.readline()
    while 'ga_group_create' not in curr_line:
        curr_line = inp_ses.readline()
    set_name = curr_line.split("\"")[1]
    recording = []
    curr_line = inp_ses.readline()
    # now looking for the next instance
    while 'ga_group_create' not in curr_line:
        recording.append(curr_line)
        curr_line = inp_ses.readline()
```

Pay no attention to the fact that the begin and end headers are the same string (just call them "begin" and "end"). The code above gives me the text between the headers only the first time they appear. I can modify it to give me the rest by keeping track of variables that increment in every instance, modifying my while statements etc but all this feels like trying to re-invent the wheel and in a very bad way too.

Is there anything out there i can make use of?

Comment: A regular expression globally (capturing) between your delimiters?

Comment: I have never used regex but the time for that might have indeed come. It's probably either that or an all-together different language built for parsing like awk.

Comment: Your code works but you want to improve it? May be better posting it to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AlG It does work in giving me the first instance of the many i want to get. So partly. I think a different approach is needed, not a code improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree regex is a good way to go here, but this is a more direct application to your problem:

```
import re

options = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE
contents = open('parsexample.txt').read()    
m = re.search('ga_group_create(.*)ga_group_create', contents, 
              options)    
lines_in_between = m.groups(0)[0].split()
```

If you have a couple of these groups, you can iterate through them:

```
for m in re.finditer('ga_group_create(.*?)ga_group_create', contents, options):
    print(m.groups(0)[0].split())
```

Notice I've used `*?` to do non-greedy matching.

Comment: Yes. If you have multiple groups, you can match non-greedily by using `*?` instead of `*`. I've added a method for handling multiple groups in my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Oye gentle stack traveller. Time hast come for thee to use the power of regex

Basic usage

```
import re
m = re.search('start(.*?)end', 'startsecretend')
m.group(1)
'secret'
```

- `.` matches any character
- `*` repeats any number of times
- `?` makes it *non greedy* i.e. it won't capture `'end'`
- `( )` indicates the group or capture

More at [Python re manual](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html)

Comment: Captain Havlicek, it seems like it should be m.group(1), right ?

Comment: I will try going full blow with this now. Thanks for the brief introduction to the seas of regex.